# Trying to use python/gspread to check if column 'B2' contains url, update column C2 with '=image(B2)' to display image in googlesheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I've searched stackoverflow and came across a bunch of variations like if/else, range(), search(), enumerate, update_Cells, batch_update, etc but I can't seem to achieve my desired result.

[Tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272851/python-gspread-changing-contents-of-a-cell-based-on-contents-of-another-cell)

`

```
import gspread

NAMES=["https"] 
gc = gspread.service_account()
spreadsheet = gc.open("SpreadsheetName") 

sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("sheet1")

data = sheet.get_all_values()
values = ["Yes" if cell.value in NAMES else "No" for b in data]
cells = sheet.range("C1:C%d" % len(values))
for i, b in enumerate(cells):
    b.value = values[i]
sheet.update_cells(cells)
```

`

Also tried this:

`

```
# Import the necessary libraries
from gspread import Client

# Authenticate with Google Sheets and open the desired spreadsheet
client = Client.from_service_account_file('/path/to/service/account/credentials.json')
spreadsheet = client.open('My Spreadsheet')

# Select the worksheet that contains the desired cells
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet('Sheet1')

# Define the regular expression pattern for a URL
url_pattern = r'(https?://)?([\w-]{2,}\.)+[\w-]{2,4}(/[\w-./?%&=_]*)?'

# Search for cells containing a URL in the desired range
results = worksheet.findall(url_pattern, 'B2:B3')

# If cells containing a URL are found, write the =image() formula in the corresponding cells
if results:
    for cell in results:
        # Get the row and column indices of the matching cell
        row = cell.row
        col = cell.col

        # Write the =image() formula in the corresponding cell in the other column
        worksheet.update_cell(row, col + 1, f'=image({worksheet.cell(row, col).address})')
```

`

But nothing seems to work!

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question and `But nothing seems to work!`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to use gspread to read column 'B3' and detect if there are urls in that column. IF there is, I would like to add the '=IMAGE( )' to the next column, while adding that row and column number 'b3' into the brackets ( ) to end up with '=IMAGE(B3)' so that in Column C3 it shows the image in cell. 

Then I would like it to go down the column and do the same for the rest, B4:B200 etc while writing in C4:c200 the same '=IMAGE('BX') where X is the row's number.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, how about putting a formula of `=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(B3:B200))` to the cell "C3"? If I misunderstood your expected goal, I apologize.

Comment: I understand what you mean, where i can just input '=IMAGE(B2)' and drag it down along column C. 

But I wish for it to be in a script form, so I can run it remotely when I am unable to access the spreadsheet and there are updates to the spreadsheet, for example when more urls are added to column B. Thus I wish to do it 'remotely' and via a py script or exe.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I understand what you mean, where i can just input '=IMAGE(B2)' and drag it down along column C.`, unfortunately, my proposed formula is not required to do that process. You just put only a formula of `=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(B3:B200))` to the cell "C3". Is this your expected result? If I misunderstood your expected goal, I apologize.

Comment: okay i understand now. 

I can just do wks.update_cell(2,3, "=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(B3:B200))") thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: do you know how to do the same for column D, where i have a '=myfunction(B2)' and I would like to go down Column D the same way? I tried =ARRAYFORMULA(MYFUNCTION(B2:B200)) but it shows error. 

Error
Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length. (line 2).

Comment: About your new question of `do you know how to do the same for column D, where i have a '=myfunction(B2)' and I would like to go down Column D the same way? I tried =ARRAYFORMULA(MYFUNCTION(B2:B200)) but it shows error. Error Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length. (line 2).`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: In column C you have helped me do =IMAGE(B2) down the column. I would like to do for column D =myFunction(B2) down the column as well, and I tried with your arrayformula method, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This is my function for google app script to check if a url image is squared or vertically long. 

function myFunction(url) {
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  const { width, height } = ImgApp.getSize(blob);
var percDiff = ( width / height ) * 100;

if (percDiff < 85) {
  return [["Story"]];
} else {
  return[["Post"]];
}
}

the result will be defined in column D, as =myFunction(B2). 

How do I set the same ArrayFormula for column D with myFunction?

Comment: @Tanaike can you post it as an answer so i can accept your answer. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I thought that I understood your 2nd question. So, I posted them as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your questions, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer to question 1:

When you want to put the formula of `=IMAGE(B3)`, `=IMAGE(B4)` ,,, to the column "C", how about putting a formula of `=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(B3:B200))` to the cell "C3"?

### Answer to question 2:

When you want to put your custom function of `=myFunction(B2)`, `=myFunction(B3)`,,, to the column "D", how about putting a formula of `=BYROW(B3:B200,LAMBDA(X,IF(X<>"",IFERROR(myFunction(X),),)))` to a cell "D3"?

Or, if you can modify your script, how about modifying your script as follows?

```js
function myFunction(urls) {
  const reqs = urls && Array.isArray(urls) ? urls.map(([url]) => (url ? { url, muteHttpExceptions: true } : null)) : [{ url: urls, muteHttpExceptions: true }];
  return reqs.map(e => {
    if (e) {
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll([e])[0];
      if (res.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        const { width, height } = ImgApp.getSize(res.getBlob());
        var percDiff = (width / height) * 100;
        return [percDiff < 85 ? "Story" : "Post"];
      }
    }
    return [null];
  });
}
```

- By this modification, you can put a custom function of `=myFunction("B3:B200")` to a cell "D3". By this, the results are returned.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've accepted both your answers, and they work!